ORACLE PL/SQL Procedure
I would like to make a Prodecure from the following PL/SQL.
Can someone help me with this?
BEGIN
  FOR c IN (SELECT id FROM test WHERE uuid IS NULL)
  LOOP
      UPDATE test
      SET uuid=(
  select lower(
        trim(to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(0, power(16, 8))), '0XXXXXXX')) || '-' ||
        trim(to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(0, power(16, 4))), '0XXX')) || '-' ||
        trim(to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(0, power(16, 4))), '0XXX')) || '-' ||
        case floor(dbms_random.value(0, 4))
          when 0 then '8'
          when 1 then '9'
          when 2 then 'A'
          when 3 then 'B'
        end ||
        trim(to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(0, power(16, 3))), '0XX')) || '-' ||
        trim(to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(0, power(16, 12))), '0XXXXXXXXXXX'))
       )
       from dual
       )
           WHERE id=c.id;
  END LOOP;
END;
/

ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'RANDOM_UUID_1'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


It looks like you have already turned that anonymous block into a procedure (or function?), called RANDOM_UUID_1, but you haven't shown that for some reason; and it's then your call to that procedure that is erroring. Without seeing the procedure definition - particularly the formal argument list - and how you are calling it, we can't tell you what you are doing wrong. (But I suspect it'll be a trivial mistake...)


Don't use loops
You are not generating a valid UUID as you are not setting the version bits.
lower and trim are unnecessary if you use x (rather than X) and fm, respectively, in the format model for TO_CHAR.

Your code can simply be:
UPDATE test
SET uuid = TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, POWER(16,8))), 'fm0xxxxxxx')
    || '-' || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, POWER(16,4))), 'fm0xxx')
    || '-' || '4' || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, POWER(16,3))), 'fm0xx')
    || '-' || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(8, 12)), 'fmx')
           || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, POWER(16,3))), 'fm0xx')
    || '-' || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, POWER(16,12))), 'fm0xxxxxxxxxxx')
WHERE uuid IS NULL;

If you want a procedure then:
CREATE PROCEDURE set_null_uuid_in_test
IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE test
  SET uuid = TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, POWER(16,8))), 'fm0xxxxxxx')
      || '-' || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, POWER(16,4))), 'fm0xxx')
      || '-' || '4' || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, POWER(16,3))), 'fm0xx')
      || '-' || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(8, 12)), 'fmx')
             || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, POWER(16,3))), 'fm0xx')
      || '-' || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, POWER(16,12))), 'fm0xxxxxxxxxxx')
  WHERE uuid IS NULL;
END;
/

Then you can call it using:
BEGIN
  set_null_uuid_in_test();
END;
/

It would seem to make more sense to wrap your UUID generation into a function (rather than a procedure):
CREATE FUNCTION random_uuid
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, POWER(16,8))), 'fm0xxxxxxx')
      || '-' || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, POWER(16,4))), 'fm0xxx')
      || '-' || '4' || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, POWER(16,3))), 'fm0xx')
      || '-' || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(8, 12)), 'fmx')
             || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, POWER(16,3))), 'fm0xx')
      || '-' || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, POWER(16,12))), 'fm0xxxxxxxxxxx');
END;
/

Then you can call it from the UPDATE:
UPDATE test
SET uuid = random_uuid()
WHERE uuid IS NULL;

Which, for the sample data (two rows with version 4 UUIDs with the random bits set to zero and three NULL rows):
CREATE TABLE test (id, uuid) AS
  SELECT LEVEL, '00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000000' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT LEVEL + 2, NULL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;

Then after calling either of the UPDATEs or the procedure the table may (randomly) contain:



ID
UUID




1
00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000000


2
00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000000


3
e90a3ebc-2398-4e3c-ab86-4f2e82e84c99


4
3ac18c6d-9dff-485f-9c10-cb719a3701bf


5
d9d462e1-6671-49f8-b731-e76aa8e44337



fiddle

It is easy to make it a stored procedure; just add appropriate command at the beginning:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_my_proc
AS
BEGIN
   FOR c IN (SELECT id
               FROM test
              WHERE uuid IS NULL)
   LOOP
      UPDATE test
         SET uuid =
                (SELECT LOWER (
                              TRIM (
                                 TO_CHAR (FLOOR (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (0, POWER (16, 8))),
                                          '0XXXXXXX'))
                           || '-'
                           || TRIM (
                                 TO_CHAR (FLOOR (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (0, POWER (16, 4))),
                                          '0XXX'))
                           || '-'
                           || TRIM (
                                 TO_CHAR (FLOOR (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (0, POWER (16, 4))),
                                          '0XXX'))
                           || '-'
                           || CASE FLOOR (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (0, 4))
                                 WHEN 0 THEN '8'
                                 WHEN 1 THEN '9'
                                 WHEN 2 THEN 'A'
                                 WHEN 3 THEN 'B'
                              END
                           || TRIM (
                                 TO_CHAR (FLOOR (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (0, POWER (16, 3))),
                                          '0XX'))
                           || '-'
                           || TRIM (
                                 TO_CHAR (FLOOR (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (0, POWER (16, 12))),
                                          '0XXXXXXXXXXX')))
                   FROM DUAL)
       WHERE id = c.id;
   END LOOP;
END;
/

Though, that's not your main problem. You reported that Oracle complains about wrong number or datatype of arguments while calling RANDOM_UUID_1 function (or procedure), but - there's no such call in code you posted.
